# File count from a folder

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do I get number of Files from a folder using ASP.NET with C#?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

```
System.IO.Directory myDir = GetMyDirectoryForTheExample();
int count = myDir.GetFiles().Length;
```

Comment: What is the behaviour if the directory contains more than int.MaxValue files?

Comment: For a more up-to-date solution that's lighter on resources, replace GetFiles() by EnumerateFiles() and Length by Count()

Answer (score 158):

You can use the **[Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx)** method

Also see **[Directory.GetFiles Method (String, String, SearchOption)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316.aspx)**

You can specify the search option in this overload.

**TopDirectoryOnly**: Includes only the current directory in a search.

**AllDirectories**: Includes the current directory and all the subdirectories in a search operation. This option includes reparse points like mounted drives and symbolic links in the search.

```
// searches the current directory and sub directory
int fCount = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
// searches the current directory
int fCount = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Length;
```

Comment: May I suggest using "*" to match for files, otherwise files without extensions won't be included in the count.

Comment: This seems to be including the count of subfolders.  That is, I have one subfolder and in an otherwise empty directory and this returns 1.

Comment: @MichaelPotter is it possible it was counting desktop.ini?

Comment: For a more up-to-date solution that's lighter on resources, replace GetFiles() by EnumerateFiles() and Length by Count()

Answer (score 31):

The slickest method woud be to use [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query):

```
var fileCount = (from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"H:\iPod_Control\Music", "*.mp3", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                        select file).Count();
```

Comment: You could just write: var fileCount = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"H:\iPod_Control\Music", "*.mp3", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Count();

Comment: I recommended this method in case of huge collections of files. This approach save memory. Method `GetFile` create string[] which required flat memory space. Be careful :)

Answer (score 18):

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo("SourcePath");
int count = dir.GetFiles().Length;
```

You can use this.

Answer (score 9):

Reading PDF files from a directory:

```
var list = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\ScanPDF", "*.pdf");
if (list.Length > 0)
{

}
```

Comment: Unneccesarily definition of a list. This should do the job: if Directory.Getfiles(@"C:\ScanPDF", "*.pdf").count >0

Comment: @StefanMeyer No if you gonna use that list later...

Comment: @GuilleBauza The question was to count the PDF files, not to use them ;)

Comment: Yes, but what's the point of counting if you won't use it...

Comment: @GuilleBauza Plenty of scenarios. Like deciding what to do w/ the folder but not caring about the files. It's simply a different scenario.

Comment: @mdelvecchio I know, I was referring to the first comment, that says it is an unnecessary use of a list definition. Which depending on the context it is not.

Comment: @GuilleBauza He's right tho it is unnecessary -- OP didn't say they needed to enumerate the files, the question was for count only. Thus his comment on your answer is correct, it unnecessarily instantiates a list when none is needed per the actual question. Two different use cases, only one of which was asked.

Answer (score 8):

.NET methods Directory.GetFiles(dir) or DirectoryInfo.GetFiles() are not very fast for just getting a total file count.
If you use this file count method very heavily, consider **using WinAPI directly**, which saves about 50% of time.

Here's the WinAPI approach where I encapsulate WinAPI calls to a C# method:

```
int GetFileCount(string dir, bool includeSubdirectories = false)
```

Complete code:

```
[Serializable, StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
private struct WIN32_FIND_DATA
{
    public int dwFileAttributes;
    public int ftCreationTime_dwLowDateTime;
    public int ftCreationTime_dwHighDateTime;
    public int ftLastAccessTime_dwLowDateTime;
    public int ftLastAccessTime_dwHighDateTime;
    public int ftLastWriteTime_dwLowDateTime;
    public int ftLastWriteTime_dwHighDateTime;
    public int nFileSizeHigh;
    public int nFileSizeLow;
    public int dwReserved0;
    public int dwReserved1;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 260)]
    public string cFileName;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 14)]
    public string cAlternateFileName;
}

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr FindFirstFile(string pFileName, ref WIN32_FIND_DATA pFindFileData);
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
private static extern bool FindNextFile(IntPtr hFindFile, ref WIN32_FIND_DATA lpFindFileData);
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
private static extern bool FindClose(IntPtr hFindFile);

private static readonly IntPtr INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = new IntPtr(-1);
private const int FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY = 16;

private int GetFileCount(string dir, bool includeSubdirectories = false)
{
    string searchPattern = Path.Combine(dir, "*");

    var findFileData = new WIN32_FIND_DATA();
    IntPtr hFindFile = FindFirstFile(searchPattern, ref findFileData);
    if (hFindFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        throw new Exception("Directory not found: " + dir);

    int fileCount = 0;
    do
    {
        if (findFileData.dwFileAttributes != FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
        {
            fileCount++;
            continue;
        }

        if (includeSubdirectories && findFileData.cFileName != "." && findFileData.cFileName != "..")
        {
            string subDir = Path.Combine(dir, findFileData.cFileName);
            fileCount += GetFileCount(subDir, true);
        }
    }
    while (FindNextFile(hFindFile, ref findFileData));

    FindClose(hFindFile);

    return fileCount;
}
```

When I search in a folder with 13000 files on my computer - Average: **110ms**

```
int fileCount = GetFileCount(searchDir, true); // using WinAPI
```

.NET built-in method: Directory.GetFiles(dir) - Average: **230ms**

```
int fileCount = Directory.GetFiles(searchDir, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
```

Note: first run of either of the methods will be 60% - 100% slower respectively because the hard drive takes a little longer to locate the sectors. Subsequent calls will be semi-cached by Windows, I guess.

Comment: Great soln but to get it working I recommend the following edit:

||||||||||||add public static long fileCount = 0;



|||||||||||| //int fileCount = 0; //comment out

Comment: This is an absolutely stellar answer!

Comment: Actually, one fix is potentially important.  Change this line:  `if (findFileData.dwFileAttributes != FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)` 

to: `if ((findFileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) == 0)`

Otherwise, a directory with any additional attribute (say the archive flag is set: 32 (0x20)) will be counted as a file rather than seen as a directory.

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-attribute-constants

Comment: Big points for taking the time to do a real performance analysis.
To get that micro optimization, it's a lot of work, but I guess if you really need the optimization for an application then this is great.  Although, you're out of luck in .net core doing this, you're married to windows only.

Answer (score 4):

```
int fileCount = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length; // Will Retrieve count of all files in directry and sub directries

int fileCount = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectory).Length; // Will Retrieve count of all files in directry but not sub directries

int fileCount = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length; // Will Retrieve count of files XML extension in directry and sub directries
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int filesCount = Directory.EnumerateFiles(Directory).Count();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try following code to get count of files in the folder

```
string strDocPath = Server.MapPath('Enter your path here'); 
int docCount = Directory.GetFiles(strDocPath, "*", 
SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Length;
```

---

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `MVC`, and your directory exists inside your project structure and in the build when it is released on `IIS` for deployment, then you can use the following method to get the count of files in a specified directory:

```
string myFilesDir = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/MyServerDirectory/");
var countFiles = (from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(myFilesDir, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                 select file).Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

The System.IO namespace provides such a facility. It contains types that allow reading and writing to files and data streams, and types that provide basic file and directory support.

For example, if you wanted to count the number of files in the `C:\` directory, you would say (Note that we had to escape the '\' character with another '\'):

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\\");
int count = dir.GetFiles().Length;
```

You could also escape the '\' character by using the verbatim string literal whereby anything in the string that would normally be interpreted as an escape sequence is ignored, i.e. instead of `("C:\\")`, you could say, `(@"C:\")`

Answer (score -2):

To get the count of certain type extensions using [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query) you could use this simple code:

```
Dim exts() As String = {".docx", ".ppt", ".pdf"}

Dim query = (From f As FileInfo In directory.GetFiles()).Where(Function(f) exts.Contains(f.Extension.ToLower()))

Response.Write(query.Count())
```