# Access Virtual Directory folder through code behind Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, directory, virtual

I am trying to access a Virtual Directory folder from Code-behind.

- ASP.Net Website Name : SuperImages
- Physical folder : C:\images
- Virtual Directory folder : allimages (In same level as App_Data, Scripts, Properties folders)

I am trying to access and do a count of the number of items in this folder, then display them on a webpage.

How should I do this?

Thanks in advance!

=======================================================================

Update : From the posts below, it seems that Server.MapPath would give me the correct physical path. However, it seems to me that I am getting the wrong physical path. Reason should be I am running 'debug' mode.

Hence, any idea how I can ensure Server.MapPath point correctly and while running in debug mode?

======================================================================

**SOLUTION :**

Problem was that on Debug mode, I was using the VS Dev Server instead of my local IIS. I re-created a Virtual Directory for my app in the local IIS. Re-created another virtual directory for the 'allimages' folder in this newly created app, and it solved the problem.

Comment: What path do you get in Debug Mode?

Comment: @BhushanFirake The path of my project : C:\users\juniordeveloper\SuperImages\allimages.

Comment: Try changing my `/` with `\\` then?

Comment: @BhushanFirake Ok, found the problem. It turns out on Debug mode, I was using the VS Dev Server instead of my local IIS. I re-created a Virtual Directory for my app in the local IIS. Re-created another virtual directory for the 'allimages' folder in this newly created app, and it solved the problem. Thanks for the help Bhushan!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
DirectoryInfo dir= new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("/allimages"));
```

Then you can get the Files in this folder as below:

```
FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles(string searchPattern,SearchOption searchOption);
```

and for tha count of files you can simply do array count.

Comment: Hi, think this should work. However I realised that Server.MapPath keeps returning me the wrong physical path. Reason should be I am running 'debug' mode. Hence, any idea how I can ensure Server.MapPath point correctly and while running in debug mode? Thanks.

Comment: @juniordeveloper87 You said that your `allimages` folder is at the same level of `App_Data`? So it should work , or your path may be different. Check it once again.

Answer (score 0):

You can access it in the same way you'd access it from a normal application. I,d use the Directory class to get a count of the items. Just make sure you have enough permissions.

```
Directory.EnumerateFiles(myPath).Length;
```

Answer (score 0):

AS suggested in the post
[File count from a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242564/file-count-from-a-folder)
You can go like this.

You can use the

**[Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx)** method

Also see **[Directory.GetFiles Method (String, String, SearchOption)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316.aspx)**

You can specify the search option in this overload.

**TopDirectoryOnly**: Includes only the current directory in a search.

**AllDirectories**: Includes the current directory and all the subdirectories in a search operation. This option includes reparse points like mounted drives and symbolic links in the search.

```
// searches current directory and sub directory
int fCount = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
// searches current directory
int fCount = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectory).Length;
```

You will have to use `Server.MapPath` for your virtual directory folder.

```
  string dir = Server.MapPath(@"/Content/slideshow/images/image");
  FileInfo[] files;
  int numFiles;
  files = (new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(dir)).GetFiles("filePattern");
  numFiles = files.Length;
```