# Not able to access Virtual Directory

Tags: vb.net, iis

I have the following code in vb.net:

```
    Dim PreApprovalDir = "/Inspections/"  ' Virtual Directory to N:\Inspections\Pre-Approval Inspections

    Dim di As New DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath(PreApprovalDir))
    Dim fiArr As FileInfo() = di.GetFiles()
    Dim fri As FileInfo
    For Each fri In fiArr
        'If fri.Name.StartsWith(FileNamePrefix) And fri.Name.EndsWith(".pdf") Then
        If fri.Name.StartsWith(FileNamePrefix) Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next fri
```

I get the following error:

```
[DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'N:\Inspections\Pre-Approval Inspections'.]
```

On the `di.GetFiles()` line.

I setup the Virtual directory using the GUI is IIS so I am confident I did not typo anything.

I am browse to N:\Inspections\Pre-Approval Inspections in windows explorer.

I am new to IIS and VB.net so this is probably some stupid error on my part.  After I get this to work I then need to get access to the files that are found:

I will be reading them like this:

```
Response.WriteFile(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(PreApprovalDir), fri.Name))
```

[EDIT] This is not the same as other StackOverflow questions because this is failing on the GetFiles() call.

How do I go about debugging this as a permissions problem on the source folder?  I can browse to the folder just fine using windows explorer.  is there something else I can check?

[EDIT: Report significant advancement]
I copied my data from N: to C: and was able to get this to work including reading the .pdf file from the disk.  Is there some restriction that Virtual Directories don't work on shared drives?  If not I will dig deeper into permissions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access Virtual Directory folder through code behind Asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15320967/access-virtual-directory-folder-through-code-behind-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

The solution was that I needed to point the Virtual Directory to

```
\\ServerN\c\somepath\
```

Rather than

```
N:\somepath\
```

IIS did not give any warnings that mapping drives does not work.

However, when I successfully mapped the subfolders appeared in IIS configuration utility.  That is when I figured out I was successful.  Because this is the first time I used Virtual Folders I did not know to look for that.