# How to correctly count the number of files in a folder

Tags: vb.net, file, count

I am making a list of folders, where each folder needs only a few properties, so I'm using the Class below. However, no matter the folder, the `FilesInFolder` property is alway 5 more than the actual number of files in the folder.

Can someone please help me find out what is wrong? Thanks.

```
Public Class Single_Action_Folder

    Public ReadOnly FullName As String = ""
    Public ReadOnly Name As String = ""
    Public ReadOnly FilesInFolder As Integer = 0
    Public ReadOnly Exists As Boolean = False

    '**
    ' Constructor
    '*
    Public Sub New(Optional dir As DirectoryInfo = Nothing)

        ' First check that a directory has been specified
        If dir Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

        ' Populate the class properties
        FullName = dir.FullName
        Name = dir.Name
        FilesInFolder = dir.GetFiles().Count
        Exists = dir.Exists

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/2242573/1954916

Comment: @Belial09: How does that link differ from what OP has already tried?

Comment: Have you looked to see what files the GetFiles enumeration is returning?

Comment: @Tim Schmelter if you have a look at the other answers on the post, there is an LINQ solution. The Answer on the link differs because there are parameters entered to the GetFiles() function.

Comment: @Belial09: However, he wants the total file count in one directory, so i don't see why using a search-pattern or search-option could help. `dir.GetFiles().Count()` should work.

Comment: Are you running this app as an administrator or with some less privileged user account?

Comment: @MarkHall - How do I do that? All of my efforts end in an error.

Comment: @Steve - I'm a admin, running the program in debug mode through Visual Studio 2012 Express. However, I'm not sure how not running as an admin would result in more than the actual number of files being counted?!

Comment: @Belial09 - I found that thread before posting. Sadly, it is of no help in thi scase. Thanks.

Comment: @MarkHall - Nevermind, I figured out how to list the files.

Comment: @Belial09 - I take it back. Directory.GetFiles("directory", "*.mp3").count worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So the issue here is that `FilesInFolder = dir.GetFiles().Count` was counting hidden files. Even though I've set Windows folder options to show hidden files/folders, they were not shown as they were things like album art. The following line sorted my issue.

```
FilesInFolder = Directory.GetFiles(FullName, "*.mp3").Count
```

I am wondering though, if there is a way to count more than one file type? I.e MP3 and WMA? If anyone happens to know, I'd apprciate a comment.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7039580/multiple-file-extensions-searchpattern-for-system-io-directory-getfiles

Comment: Cheers @Garath, will have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Check you do not have hidden files in tested directories. I check your code on my PC and it is working good.

Comment: While you are at it, what happen if you set the hidden attribute to a file?

Comment: No hidden files in any of the directories that I have tested. Thanks.

Comment: Odd - even though hidden files are set to be showen, there is apparently 5 files in each of my music folders (album art, etc), that do not show up...

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim FilesInFolder = Directory.GetFiles("C:\BGS\TemporaryProjects\Images\", "*.mp3").Count
    Dim i As Integer = 1
    While i <= FilesInFolder
        ListBox1.Items.Add(i)
        i += 1
    End While
End Sub
```