# How can I get a count of files in a directory with scripting on Wonderware Archestra IDE

Tags: wonderware

Two files "test.txt" and "test2.txt" were created in C:\tmp_dir. I want to know how many files in "C:\tmp_dir". 
My code:

```
    dim s as string;
    s = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\tmp_dir");
    LogMessage(s.Length);
```

But it's obviously wrong. It's returns 40(amount of symbols in path and both files) instead of 2. How can I do this properly?

Answer (score 1):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/15867350/804773 :

```
dim s as Integer;
s = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\tmp_dir").Count();
LogMessage(Text(s,"#"));
```

Comment: Thanks, but I tried this and it didn't work. "Unknown property: Count". I think it  is because of specific scripting in Wonderware Archestra IDE.

Comment: Keep in mind, these are just standard .NET library functions you should be able to find ample documentation on MSDN or other resources for .NET. In this case I think `Count` may be a function (not a Property) and would be accessed by `.Count()` as I've edited into my answer

Answer (score 1):

Tanks a lot! As you mentioned "s" must be Integer not string. And with "length" instead of "count" works fine.

```
dim s as integer;
s = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\tmp_dir").length;
LogMessage(s);
```