# Counting the number of files in a folder in c#

Tags: c#

I am a newbie to programming and need help to create a windows application in C# to count the number of files in a folder.

What method would I use to make it count?

**Update 02/01/2016

Exactly what it says, the amunt of files contained inside the folder.

e.g. If a folder contains 3 image files and 3 text files then the application should return the value 6.

Comment: Responsed in Stackoverflow question 2242564. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242564/file-count-from-a-folder

Comment: Search before asking question please

Answer (score 14):

You should use the [Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3hwtke0f.aspx) method.

```
int fileCount = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\MyFolder").Length;
```

If you want to search the subdirectories, too, you can use the following code:

```
int fileCount = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\MyDir\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
```

Note that if the directory does not exist a [DirectoryNotFoundException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directorynotfoundexception.aspx) will be thrown, so if you are not sure whether the directory exists or not you can either use a try ... catch block or check if the directory exists using the [Directory.Exists method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists.aspx):

```
if (Directory.Exists(dirName))
{
    // Your code here
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
// This searches in the current directory and also sub directories
int folderCount = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
// This searches only in the current directory
int folderCount = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectory).Length;
```

Good luck!

Comment: This (in combination with your user name) should be on the top 10 list of best comments ever!

Comment: I'm German, so I'm pretty positive about Obama, but I know that a significant number of US citizens think "Thanks Obama!! - Yuck". </PoliticalDiscussion>

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `System.IO.DirectoryInfo`;

```
DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(your folder path);
info.GetFiles().Count();
```

Or as suggested:

```
info.EnumerateFiles();
```

Comment: `EnumerateFiles` is better. Especially if you are using the `Count()` extension.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\SomeFolder").Length;
```

Be aware that if the directory doesn't exist this will throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

The `DirectoryInfo` class will help you.

```
var info = new DirectoryInfo("D:\\");
var files = info.GetFiles();
var dirs = info.GetDirectories();
files.Length;
dirs.Length;
```