# File count from web folder in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, directory

How to count total file from website folder?

```
string uri = "http://company.co.id/folder/"
public int CountTotalFile(string uri)
{
   ...
   return total;
}
```

Sorry, I have no idea and can't provide some website URL.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242564/file-count-from-a-folder

Comment: I don't think it is possible as you are counting a web-application or web site image. As I know you can not browse the directory of a web application. It can be done if it is a folder inside your application.

Comment: thanks for opinion, it seems I must find another solution.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the answer "It's not possible to get list of files via http" but here I would like to add my comments with different method as access the folder like a "crawler".

Is that possible to simulate the crawler to check all of the links in your company's folder which shared in website?

If meet a file, it must contains some suffix just like: *.exe, *.txt and etc. Just check that as a string and count it.

I just supply my methods for your information, hopes it can help to fix the issue :).