# Counting files C#

Tags: c#, count

I want to count the files in a folder

```
int fCount = Directory.GetFiles(@"path", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
    Console.WriteLine(fCount);
    Console.ReadLine();
```

the result was around 3200 but when I'm opening the folder, it's showing me 1600 elements in it. So why did I get the double of Elements with my program?

Comment: Side-note: as opposed to what the title suggests you are not counting only text-files. Also, where was the folder showing 1600 files? You know the purpose of `SearchOption.AllDirectories`?

Comment: Did you just directly copy [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2242573/2596334)?

Comment: @Tim you are right -  I will change the title. But the folder only contains text files...

Comment: @TimSchmelter http://img5.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/20141014170f7ay1gvtc9.png .. 1.641

Comment: If the folder only contains '.txt' files why don't you try changing your search pattern "\*" to "\*.txt" to ensure this is working correctly?

Comment: The new result is zero - lol

Comment: so you've got Directory.GetFiles(@"path", "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length? What about if you changed your search pattern to "\*.\*"?

Comment: Ah ok - I got with *.txt - 3283 and with "." 3285 - the double amount of the elements, which are displayed in the folder.

Comment: Are there any subfolders? If so your current SearchOption counts all the files in those as well.

Comment: Ok - I got the right number now - thank you!

Comment: What was the answer? If it's none of the supplied comments / answers then put your own in and mark it as correct so people know this question has been answered successfully.

Answer (score 1):

At a guess, youre using `AllDirectories` as your search option. This will recurse into any child directories of the one youve specified, and count matching files in those aswell.

Answer (score 0):

The SearchOption.AllDirectories includes the current directory and all its subdirectories in the search.  When you open the folder it is only showing you the current directory items.