# Method to Get File Path and the number of files within it

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I am new to `C#` and I need help in adding a method to a pretty well compiled program already.

I have the following code:

```
class Program
    {
        private static readonly ILog log =
            LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var startTimeOfApplication = DateTime.Now;
            Helper.SetFileAppenderLogFile();
            Console.WriteLine("Started executing the MPL File processor at :: " + startTimeOfApplication);
            log.Info("Started exection at :: " + DateTime.Now);
            var filesPath = string.Empty;
            if (args.Length > 0)
            {
                filesPath = args[0];
            }
            else
            {
                filesPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mplFilesPath"].ToString();
            }
            log.Info("MPL Files Path " + filesPath);
            var mplFilesProcessor = new MPLFilesProcessor();
            mplFilesProcessor.ProcessMPLFiles(filesPath);

            var endTimeOfApplication = DateTime.Now;
            Console.WriteLine("Completed MPL Files Processor exection at :: " + endTimeOfApplication);
            log.Info("Completed MPL Files Processor exection at :: " + endTimeOfApplication);
            log.Info(string.Format("Total time taken to process is {0} minutes ", endTimeOfApplication.Subtract(startTimeOfApplication).TotalMinutes));
        }
```

I have the **path of a directory** saved to a `String` variable, and I want to get that **path and count the number of files** within that.

Please assist in how I should go about writing that method?

Appreciate the help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File count from a folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242564/file-count-from-a-folder)

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Your question is already clear without the code. Consider removing it completely from the question because it is very confusing.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get the number of files within a directory, you could do this:

```
int numberOfFiles = Directory.GetFiles(path).Count();
```

If you want to get all the file system entries within that directory (which includes other directories):

```
int numberOfFiles = Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(path).Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to simply call `Directory.GetFiles()` and get the `Length` property.

```
var path = @"C:\Windows";
var fileCount = Directory.GetFiles(path).Length;
Console.WriteLine("{0} has {1} files in it", path, fileCount);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to navigate to directory path and get file count.

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(@"C:\somedir");
int count = dir.GetFiles().Length;
```