# count number of files in FTP Directory Using C#

Tags: c#, .net

Is there any way to count number of files present in FTP directory using C# CODE.
I do not have access to use SSIS and hence I have to accomplish this task using Visual Studio.

Comment: You need all the files present in a directory? Refer this- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14877237/getting-all-file-names-from-a-folder-using-c-sharp

Comment: I dont wan the file name..I just need the count of files.

Comment: The text 'C# ftp count files' plugged into google yields a complete tutorial as the first result. Please do research before posting questions like this. Yes, of course it's possible to count the number of files in FTP. Do some research.

Comment: Did you Google this? It's pretty common. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242564/file-count-from-a-folder

Comment: @rob,@souvik-my primary task is to get number of files from FTP location and email the same to the user.How do i do it..??

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code,

```
public static String[] FTPListTree(String FtpUri, String User, String Pass) {

List<String> files = new List<String>();
Queue<String> folders = new Queue<String>();
folders.Enqueue(FtpUri);

while (folders.Count > 0) {
    String fld = folders.Dequeue();
    List<String> newFiles = new List<String>();

    FtpWebRequest ftp = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(fld);
    ftp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(User, Pass);
    ftp.UsePassive = false;
    ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
    using (StreamReader resp = new StreamReader(ftp.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())) {
        String line = resp.ReadLine();
        while (line != null) {
            newFiles.Add(line.Trim());
            line = resp.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    ftp = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(fld);
    ftp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(User, Pass);
    ftp.UsePassive = false;
    ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;
    using (StreamReader resp = new StreamReader(ftp.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())) {
        String line = resp.ReadLine();
        while (line != null) {
            if (line.Trim().ToLower().StartsWith("d") || line.Contains(" <DIR> ")) {
                String dir = newFiles.First(x => line.EndsWith(x));
                newFiles.Remove(dir);
                folders.Enqueue(fld + dir + "/");
            }
            line = resp.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    files.AddRange(from f in newFiles select fld + f);
}
return files.ToArray();
}
```

You can also use the followning code:

```
   List<string> strList = new List<string>();

  FtpWebRequest fwr = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://" + ftpServerIP));
  fwr.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUserID, ftpPassword);
  fwr.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;

    //Can object of type StreamReader as given below
  StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fwr.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());  
  string str = sr.ReadLine();
        while (str != null)
        {
            strList.Add(str);
            str = sr.ReadLine();
        }
        Console.WriteLine(strList.Count);
```

Comment: into the first code..where do i need to write the FTP IP.??

Comment: You can call that method with the ip, username and password. Pass these 3 parameters to the function

Comment: getting error as ftpUserID does not exist.

Comment: After passing values..Getting No output..Kindly help me with that

Comment: Error encountered-check the stus property of exception\