# WebView2 - Access The Virtual Host

Tags: webview2

I setup WebView2 to have a virtual host and I am able to access an image based on a URL.

The problem that i have is that i need get the number of files stored in the "virtual folder". Is that possible with WebView2?

```
var env = await Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync(userDataFolder: MyCacheDirectory);
await this.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(env);
this.CoreWebView2.SetVirtualHostNameToFolderMapping(hostName, MyCacheDirectory, CoreWebView2HostResourceAccessKind.DenyCors);
//How do i access MyCacheDirectory via WebView2?
```

Comment: This is not a matter of WebView2 or any other web client. The decisive factor is wheter or not the server exposes such listing.

Answer (score 3):

Its not possible via WebView2 APIs but it is possible via .NET APIs.

[`SetVirtualHostNameToFolderMapping`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.setvirtualhostnametofoldermapping?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.818.41#Microsoft_Web_WebView2_Core_CoreWebView2_SetVirtualHostNameToFolderMapping_System_String_System_String_Microsoft_Web_WebView2_Core_CoreWebView2HostResourceAccessKind_) lets you specify a local folder and a hostname and then allows you to access the files in that local folder and subfolders as https URIs using the provided hostname. WebView2 does not provide any metadata about the files or folders available via the virtual host name mapping.

However, you can use .NET file system APIs to count the number of files in the folder you provided to `SetVirtualHostNameToFolderMapping`. For example:

```
System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(MyCacheDirectory).Length;
```

See [File count from a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242564/file-count-from-a-folder) for more information on counting files in a folder.

Comment: "MyCacheDirectory" is stored in my local machine but my goal would be to store it in back end server. Accessing html files located in another server should be possible with an http request. But "Getfiles" does not take a URL as a parameter.

Comment: SetVirtualHostNameToFolderMapping exists to let WebView2 access a local folder on the host app's machine as if it were an https URI. You can't use SetVirtualHostNameToFolderMapping with something other than a file path like a URI. But if you're trying to render content that's on a back end server and accessed via an http request then you shouldn't need SetVirtualHostNameToFolderMapping since you can navigate the WebView2 directly to the content accessible via http. You'll need to find another mechanism to expose the count of files in that case.