# WebView2 in WebUI3: how to disable CORS for fetch requests?

Tags: c#, .net, cors, webview2, winui-3

I have a simple web app I would like to run in a WinUI app that can fetch external HTML content:

```
    private async fetchHtml() {
        const url = document.querySelector<HTMLInputElement>("#txt-url")!.value;
        const html = await fetch(url).then(r => r.text());
        document.querySelector<HTMLTextAreaElement>("#txt-html")!.value = html;
    }
```

Obviously this would hit a CORS error. I want to disable it but cannot find any way for WinUI3:

- [WebView2 in WinUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/winui/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.webview2.ensurecorewebview2async?view=winui-3.0) does not have `EnsureCoreWebView2Async` overload that takes `CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions` so [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67704007/653457) does not help.
- The URL is external URL so `SetVirtualHostNameToFolderMapping` suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70503083/webview2-in-winui-3-cors-errors-when-loading-an-ionic-angular-application-from) does not help as well.
- I tried injecting my own CORS header but it does not work on `fetch` (`WebResourceResponseReceived` event is not fired only on `fetch` requests):

```cs
c.WebResourceResponseReceived += (_, e) =>
{
    var origin = e.Request.Headers.FirstOrDefault(q => q.Key == "Origin").Value;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(origin))
    {
        e.Response.Headers.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
            new Uri(e.Request.Uri).GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority));
        e.Response.Headers.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*");
        e.Response.Headers.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

So it turns out you actually need to handle proxying the request in the `WebResourceRequested` event. `WebResourceResponseReceived` is [triggered *after* the browser handles the request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/how-to/webresourcerequested?tabs=dotnet#sequence-for-modifying-requests).

To proxy the request manually, you need to first set up a [web resource requested filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.addwebresourcerequestedfilter?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1343.22).

```cs
// CoreWebView2WebResourceContext.XmlHttpRequest is triggered
// by fetches for some reason. This filter will listen for any URI.
this.webView.CoreWebView2.AddWebResourceRequestedFilter("*", CoreWebView2WebResourceContext.XmlHttpRequest);
```

Then you can set up a listener just like for `WebResourceResponseReceived`

```cs
this.webView.CoreWebView2.WebResourceRequested += this.CoreWebView2_WebResourceRequested;
```

So to proxy the request, you need to set up an [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-6.0) and handle the requests manually.

For example, this will proxy all requests, assuming `httpClient` is defined as an `HttpClient`:

```cs
private void CoreWebView2_WebResourceRequested(object sender, CoreWebView2WebResourceRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    HttpRequestMessage request = new(new HttpMethod(e.Request.Method), e.Request.Uri)
    {
        Content = new StreamContent(e.Request.Content)
    };

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> header in e.Request.Headers)
    {
        // Copy base headers
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation(header.Key, header.Value);

        // Copy content headers
        request.Content.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation(header.Key, header.Value);
    }

    // Make the request
    HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.Send(request);

    // Custom headers
    response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

    // Webview2 Response expecting headers in a string with following format:
    //   key: value
    //   header2: value
    List<string> headers = response.Headers.Select(h => $"{h.Key}: {string.Join(",", h.Value)}").ToList();

    // Create Webview2 response
    CoreWebView2WebResourceResponse webView2WebResourceResponse = this.webView.CoreWebView2.Environment.CreateWebResourceResponse(
        response.Content.ReadAsStream(),
        (int)response.StatusCode,
        response.ReasonPhrase,
        string.Join('\n', headers));

    e.Response = webView2WebResourceResponse;
}
```

##### NOTE

Should not use `async` methods when building out a response object. The COM layer does not respect threading.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! I heard that they added [the option](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/2471#issuecomment-1182657427) here but haven't got the chance to test it myself if you don't want setting up a proxy

Comment: I typically disable web security, but there is something to be said for a custom proxy for requests if you need more rigid validation.

Comment: This won't work for WinUI3, as you CANNOT use blocking sync method in main thread (which will be the thread calling the callback)