# Webview2 Intercept inner css file redirection

Tags: javascript, c#, css, typescript, webview2

In my WPF app I have a Webview2 and I implemented a custom interceptor to intercept all http requests based on *WebResourceRequested event*.
However, I have a redirection to a css file that in itself it contains a reference to a woff2 file( font file).
The css looks like this :

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: RobotoFallback;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    src: url(./assets/fonts/roboto/Roboto-500.woff2) format("woff2")
}
```

The Webview2 interceptor is not catching the redirection to the .woff2 file and I am ending with a CORS error.
I tried the solution on this question [WebView2 in WebUI3: how to disable CORS for fetch requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72310839/webview2-in-webui3-how-to-disable-cors-for-fetch-requests) But it doesn't seem to work because the interceptor is not intercepting the redirection.
Any Ideas ?

Comment: "*I have a redirection to a css file*" - what exactly does that mean, how do you redirect?

Comment: @PoulBak I have an index.html that I am navigating to, inside of it there is a reference to a css external file. Inside this css file I have the above snippet. Webview2 is redirecting(the url change is getting intercepted) to the css file normally,but it is not intercepting the change to the woff2 file.

Comment: You have to show the code that is 'redirecting'. I think what is happening is that the original css file file is loaded BEFORE you're redirecting.